# MYSQL запрос выборки данных за последние полные! 11 месяцев и текущий

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Сейчас такой запрос (см. ниже) возвращает данные за последние 365 дней. Т.е. например если сегодня 15 ноября 2022 года, то в выборке будут присутствовать данные 15-31 нояб 2021 года и 1-14 нояб 2022. А необходимо получить данные за последние ПОЛНЫЕ 11 мес и 1 текущий.

Т.е. если сегодня 15 ноября 2022 года, то необходимо получить данные за полные 12/2021, 01-10/2022 и неполный текущий 1-15/11/2022.

`` SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `date` <= NOW() AND `date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `content` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')
                 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.